# Azure Api management for connecting to application

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I need to connect my api management to connect to an application.

example I need to connect to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) when I click on api management URL.https://test.azure-api.net/.

Could you please guide me the steps, as I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To create your API, you should have API management service working. If you do not have APIM service follow these steps and create one : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/get-started-create-service-instance
2. When APIM service created, Create your first API by clicking on Add API and select blank template as shown below:
   [image]
3. On the API details screen, provide the API name and display name inputs.
   Click on create button.
   [image]

API will be created successfully.
Ensure to give backend service name as your service - **[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)**

4. In the API, create a operation like get/post
   [image]

Give the details of your operation and click save,your API will be ready. Use the Test window in APIM portal to test your API
[image]