# Pipelining API calls using Azure APIM Policies

Tags: azure-api-management, policies, ibm-api-management

I'm somewhat new to Azure APIM and am trying to figure out solution to a scenario which I've be tasked to solve using APIM Policies. Here's how the workflow is supposed to work:

1. System A makes a REST call to the APIM gateway.
2. This triggers APIM to call REST API endpoint B to a get value x.
3. Finally, APIM needs to relay the original call received from system A to system C such that the header information from the System A's call and value x from endpoint B's call are included.

Thus, is there a way to accomplish this using only a combination of Azure APIM policies?

Thanks,

Comment: I've edited the original question to make a correction.

Answer (score 0):

1 & 2. You can connect System A to System B via Azure APIM gateway. You can connect APIM with system B as steps suggested in answer :  [Azure Api management for connecting to application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71136614/azure-api-management-for-connecting-to-application/71136764#71136764)
After connection, the REST API URL will be ready which you can call from system A and setup connection.

3.All the parameters (headers/payload) sent to API by calling service (System A) will be passed to System B as it is unless you make changes.

Comment: Thank you, but I just realized there was a mistake in my question which I have just corrected.

Comment: @Vishal, In Azure APIM, Create API to connect system A to System C. In inbound policy section, use the send request policy. Using send request policy (Ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#SendRequest ), trigger system B rest API.  Store the output of send request into the variable and then all details can be passed to backend service (service C).